# Как можно генерить рандомные строки определенной длины

Tags: c++, строки

Есть ли в boost или std библиотека, позволяющая генерить рандомные строки определенной длины. Нужна функция, которая будет способна генерить определенное количество не повторяющихся рандомных строк(к примеру 10000 не должны повторяться).

Comment: на счет стандартной функции с такими свойствами не знаю, а что мешает по словарю сгенерировать строку и добавить ее в множество строк, если не добавилось - сгенерировать еще раз и т.д.

Comment: Если гарантированно не повторяющиеся - значит, уже не рандомные :)

Comment: @Harry, можно детерменированные, например от числа

Comment: А что, случайные числа не повторяются?... На то они и случайные, что 1 1 1 - тоже может быть в последовательности истинно случайных чисел...

Comment: @Harry, я думаю, подойдет хеш-функция, принимающая число, и выдающая строку

Comment: Без вопросов. Такая хеш-функция, например, просто запись числа с ведущими нулями или пробелами, что удобнее...